# calculate if number bigger than defined percent of numbers in list without storing list in memory after first calculation

Tags: python, math

I have `percent value` and `list` with *fixed* length (mean that list must always has same length). In loop inputting `x` with type `int`. Task is to know if `x` is **bigger** than %
of elements, after delete first element and append to end inputted `x`.

My code:

```
needed_percent = .9975
arr = [x for x in range(1, 10_000+1)]

while True:
    x = int(input('Enter number: '))
    count_less_than_x = 0
    for n in arr:
        if x > n:
            count_less_than_x += 1
    percent = count_less_than_x / len(arr)

    if percent >= needed_percent:
        print(f'Yes! Input number={x} bigger than {needed_percent*100}% elements in list')
    else:
        print(f'No. Input number={x} less than {needed_percent*100}% elements in list')

    del arr[0]
    arr.append(x)
```

Some test for example:

```
Enter number: 1000
No. Input number=1000 less than 99.75% elements in list
Enter number: 9990
Yes! Input number=9990 bigger than 99.75% elements in list
Enter number: 9975
No. Input number=9975 less than 99.75% elements in list
Enter number: 9976
No. Input number=9976 less than 99.75% elements in list
Enter number: 9977
Yes! Input number=9977 bigger than 99.75% elements in list
Enter number: 9977
No. Input number=9977 less than 99.75% elements in list
Enter number:
```

It's working *alright...* in this case, but in other real case i have few thousands of arrays and 300k elements in each.

I don't want to store array in memory after running loop **if it's even possible**. Other words i hope that there is some math solution to calculate some value before loop, delete array from memory and then get same results on every iteration.

Please, write feedback what do you think about possibility of this even if you think (or sure) it's impossible

Comment: You could try using a [Binary Search Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-data-structure/) to get a log2(n) complexity. That would reduce the calculations a lot.

Comment: @Biskweet great idea to speed up calculations, but i think that it wouldn't reduce memory usage

Comment: No it would not, might even increase. But for this amount of data the size is acceptable. If you have 2'000 arrrays of 300'000 elements each that's 6 gigs of RAM. I'm assuming you have more, and if not you can store them in disk with [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to only process a smaller subset.

Comment: Nevermind I added an extra zero (also didn't count the fact than an integer in Python is 4 B). 2'000 arrays of 300'000 integers is 600'000'000 * 4 = 2.4 GB of RAM. Still acceptable though.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

1. Store the list in an sqlite database, and run a query to get the result. That should be memory efficient and not require storing the list in memory.
2. If you want a simpler alternative to one, you could store the list in a file and read the values one at a time from the file, although deleting the first entry will be trickier in this case. a) You could overwrite the value with a string that you will know to skip when you read it next time. b) or you could create a new file as you read values from the current file and insert the values skipping the first one, and appending the new value to it. Then deleting the file you read from.